# MediaWiki attempts to login after entering several wrong passwords

Tags: mediawiki, passwords

When requesting a new password from MediaWiki, but failing to enter the correct password, the account will be locked for a day before allowing a request for a new password again. During this period, even administration account can't do anything to unlock the account.

Is there any way to unlock the account right away?

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic, as it's about an installable script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a [maintenance script](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aChangePassword.php):

```
php changePassword.php --user="username" --password="password"
```

[More Info about running maintenance scripts](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aMaintenance_scripts)

Or [modify the database](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aResetting_passwords#Direct_database_modification):

```
UPDATE user SET user_password = CONCAT(':B:somesalt:', MD5(CONCAT('somesalt-', MD5('somepass')))) WHERE user_name = 'someuser';
```

Alternatively you you can install an [extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPassword_Reset) which allows other administrators to reset your password.